# MVC 3 Razor DropdownListFor client side ValidationMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

After looking and doing everything recommended both on Stack and in online tutorials, I can't seem to get my validation working. Did I set this up correctly? Any guidance is much appreciated! I set it up like this:

**Edit**
Int is now nullable per suggestions. But still not working.

**Model**

```
 public class Subscribers

        [Display(Name = "Channel: ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Channel is required")]
        public int? SelectedChannelID { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChannelSelectList
                {
                    get
                    {
                        Models.SwitchboardEntities db = new Models.SwitchboardEntities();
                        List<Models.Channel> channelList = db.Channels.ToList();

                        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList =
                            from channel in channelList
                            select new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = channel.name,
                                Value = channel.id.ToString()
                            };

                        return selectList;
                    }

                }
```

**View**

```
  @model Switchboard.Models.Subscribers  

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

         @Html.LabelFor(xModels => xModels.SelectedChannelID)
         @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedChannelID, Model.ChannelSelectList, "--Select Channel--", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "ChannelsDDL" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(xModels => xModels.SelectedChannelID)
```

**webconfig**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Have you included the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file in your layout, or in that particular view? Do you get any JS-errors, or what happens?

Comment: fair point. I've included those yes. No JS errors.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? How do you know validation is not occurring? From the code it appears the only possible invalid state is if the user does not select an item in the drop-down, but there is no way to not select an item in the drop-down.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan when they choose Select Channel it has a value of nothing since I'm validating the ID (which is the value of the drop down). So it should be an error, or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that argument to `DropDownListFor()`. I do think the problem is in the ID attribute added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that this dropdown is placed inside a form. For client side validation to work you need a form context or the Html helpers won't emit any HTML5 data-* attributes:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(xModels => xModels.SelectedChannelID)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedChannelID, 
        Model.ChannelSelectList, 
        "--Select Channel--", 
        new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "ChannelsDDL" } }
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(xModels => xModels.SelectedChannelID)    
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and if this is not inside a form (for example this dropdown list is inside a partial and the corresponding form is outside of this partial) you can manually simulate a form context to force the helpers generate the necessary attributes:

```
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}

@Html.LabelFor(xModels => xModels.SelectedChannelID)
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedChannelID, 
    Model.ChannelSelectList, 
    "--Select Channel--", 
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "ChannelsDDL" } }
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(xModels => xModels.SelectedChannelID)
```

Look at the source code of the generated page. Make sure that the `<select>` tag is decorated with HTML5 data-* attributes like that:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Channel:  must be a number." data-val-required=" Channel is required" id="ChannelsDDL" name="SelectedChannelID">
    ...
</select>
```

If there are not data-* attributes client side validation won't work.

Server side validation of course will work in all cases.

Comment: Face in hands...forgot the form. Thanks Darin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could validate anything.

`SelectedChannelID` is an int, and non-nullable.  Therefore, it always has a selected value.. and thus Required will never fire.  Required will only fire if the value is null, which is impossible if you use an int.

Comment: made it nullable int. Still a problem. Thanks Mystere!

Comment: Upon further analysis.  I notice you're renaming the ID of the control.  What happens if you don't do that?

Comment: I think Mystere Man has it here. ValidationMessageFor points to the putative ID of the control it validates, which it assumes to be name of the property.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the comments above, also verify that unobtrusive validation is turned on in your web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```